# Javascript validations(Letters only and Numbers only)

Tags: c#, javascript

I have created web form with different text boxes with C# code at the back. So i want to use Java Script to validate some text boxes in order to have a good website.

i am asking help from the following this.

1. i want a text box to allow **Only numbers** and when u type letters it must highlight the text boxes into red color and shows error message (Please Enter Numbers only) .
2. i want a text box to allow **Letter numbers** and when u type letters it must highlight the text boxes into red color and shows error message (Please Letters Numbers only) .

Comment: Answer for first can be found at https://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values/

Comment: Also you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Comment: Please explain what you have tried to resolve this.

Comment: Search for RequiredFieldValidators, RegularExpressionValidators, in google it will save you a lot of time and you wont have to write any javascript

Answer (score 1):

For Letters Only

```
function lettersOnly(e) {
     var k;
     document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
     return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8);
}
```

For Numbers Only

```
function numberOnly(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
```

or you can use `<input type="number">` to allow only number in the texbox

Answer (score 0):

For letter only

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Letter").keypress(function (evt) {
 var cc = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode); 
 if ((cc > 64 && cc < 91) || (cc > 96 && cc < 123) || cc == 32 || cc == 8 || cc == 127 || cc == 46 || cc == 9) {
        return true;
    }
});



$("#Number").keypress(function (evt) {
 var cc = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode); 
      if ((cc > 47 && cc < 58) || cc == 43 || cc == 44 || cc == 45 || cc == 40 || cc == 41 || cc == 32 || cc == 46 || cc == 8 || cc == 127 || cc == 9) {
            return true;
            }
     else {
                evt.cancelBubble = true;
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
});
  });
```

In this `Letter` and `Number` is textbox Id

Comment: Did you just type this, or did you copy paste it from another answer on SO or some other site? If the latter, please have the courtesy to at least link to it.

Comment: I have implement this on my project

Comment: this is the code i have ...                                      function lettersOnly(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
            var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
          ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
          (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
                alert("Enter letters only.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: Not working                                                           
$("#Number").keypress(function (evt) {
var cc = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode);
if ((cc > 47 && cc < 58) || cc == 43||cc == 44 || cc == 45 || cc == 40 || cc == 41||cc == 32||cc == 46||cc == 8|| cc == 127 || cc == 9) {
       return true;
        }
        else {
            evt.cancelBubble = true;
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });  <asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicyStatus"  onkeypress="return keypress(function (evt)" runat="server"  Width="250px"

Comment: No need to add keypress. My code should be inside document.ready

Comment: i must just include 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> your code goes here   </script>

Comment: I have copied all your codes and nothing its happening... it still allows numbers in letters text boxes